# How do I add a vertical marker to a bootstrap multiple color progress bar in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, progress-bar, react-bootstrap

I tried making another progress bar and use it as the marker but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my progress bar

```
<ProgressBar>
   <ProgressBar className="progressbar-yellow" now={25} key={1} />
   <ProgressBar className="progressbar-green" now={20} key={2} />
   <ProgressBar className="progressbar-orange" now={15} key={3} />
   <ProgressBar className="progressbar-red" now={40} key={4} />
</ProgressBar>
```

and this is my CSS

```
.progressbar-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.progressbar-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.progressbar-orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.progressbar-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.